# How to add file uploader field to Joomla admin component?

Tags: php, xml, joomla, joomla2.5

I made Joomla admin component according to Joomla guide - http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Developing_a_Basic_Component

In administrator\components\com_invoicemanager\models\forms i have defined `<field name="invoice" type="file"/>`

Now I need to capture uploaded file and save it on the disk.

How to do it ?

Comment: May this answer/question be helpful-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882459/upload-multiple-images-in-a-joomla-component

Answer (score 2):

```
Now how can i save it?
```

This is a bit vague. You will need to provide more detail and possibly something you have already tried.

You might also be interested in an [SWFUpload Component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management/21091)

It has been made very simple, to allow easy integration into other components.

Comment: Thanks, How can i integrate it inside my component ?

Comment: Copy over the model, controller and view to your component. There are also some parameters for the component so you will need to copy the config.xml too, else replace specific things such as the max file size with a default value.